# How can I delete leading spaces from each Excel cell?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Assume the following Excel sheet:

```
  | A
--+-----
1 |foo bar
2 |  bar baz
3 |   baz
4 | bam
```

I need a way to automatically delete all *leading* spaces:

```
  | A
--+-----
1 |foo bar
2 |bar baz
3 |baz
4 |bam
```

I am unable to find an Excel function to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Excel does have a `TRIM` function, but it removes all leading, tailing and excess spaces...

Comment: Thanks. I now applied in cell `B1` the formula `=TRIM(A1)` and extended it all the way down the column. On a second note, you you know how I can replace the first space (after having removed the leading spaces) by a [return]? So it becomes `foo[return]bar` for instance?

Comment: If you are concerned about removing extra spaces in between you can create your own function using RTrim and LTrim in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the cells to hold the converted values as well as the `[return]` for spaces in between words then use the following code:

```
'DECLARE VARIABLES
Dim myRng As Range, c As Range

'INITIALIZE VARIABLES
Set myRng = Range("A1:A4")

'LOOP THRU RANGE
For Each c In myRng.Cells
    'TRIM LEADING AND TRAILING SPACES
    c.Value = LTrim(c.Value)
    c.Value = RTrim(c.Value)
Next c

'ADD RETURN SPACE
myRng.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart
```

Comment: Better to write this to an array,manipulate it there, and then dump it back to a range - range loops can be very slow

Comment: @brettdj This is an excellent point regarding performance.  For a range this small I prefer the above since the code is more concise.  However, for larger ranges I would recommend visiting this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for examples utilizing arrays when working with range values.

Comment: @Taliesin +1 to your solution. And my attempt below in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170502/641067

Answer (score 2):

Use `=Trim(A1)` to remove whitespce from either side of a string.

To replace the remaining whitespace character with a linebreak, you can use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",[X])` where `[X]` is one of:

- `Char(10)` {for a line break}
- `Char(13)` {for a carriage return}
- [type] `Alt+Enter` to manually insert a line break character into an Excel cell

**Help reference**

`TRIM(text)`
Removes all spaces from text except for single spaces between words.

`SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text, [instance_num])` Substitutes `new_text` for `old_text` in a text string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very quickly with the array approach below which avoids loops altogether

While the code effectively could be run in a single long line I have broken it out for clarity.

This will update the cells to the immediate right of the original range.

```
Sub UpDateIt()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strText As String
    strText = ","
    Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    With Application
        x = Replace(Replace(.Trim(Join(.Transpose(rng1), strText)), ", ", ","), Chr(32), Chr(10))
        rng1.Offset(0, 1) = .Transpose(Split(x, strText))
    End With
End Sub
```